# javascript setInterval where page not loaded

Tags: javascript, ajax, setinterval

I want to load an function while I'm using ajax and setInterval where the page is not loaded. This function have to load every 5 seconds everytime in the background without opening the page.

How can I solve it?
thanks

Comment: have a look at.https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: Could you add details. What do you mean by "in the background without opening the page"? Is should act as a service?

Comment: $( document ).ready(function() {

 function test1() {
$.ajax({
 url: 'timeneu.php',
 success: function () { }
});
}
setInterval(function(){ test1() },1000);
});

Comment: I want that the code also runs in the background, without have to open the page

Answer (score 0):

are you using jQuery?

if so try

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  //your code
});
```

Comment: I try that, but the code runs when I open the page.  
I want that the code also runs in the background, without have to open the page